# getSelection / collapse Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, dojo, microsoft-edge

I'm on a website, using an old version of Dojo, https://dojotoolkit.org/ (old because it's will be to difficult to change every thing in my office).

with Edge, we have troubles.... One is on the function "collapse". 
Our dojo was modified to have "dojo.isEdge" to detect this new browser.
first I had

```
if(window.getSelection && !dojo.isIE){
    var selection = dojo.global.getSelection();
    if(selection.removeAllRanges){ // Mozilla
        if(beginning){
            selection.collapseToStart();
        }else{
            selection.collapseToEnd();
        }
    }else if(dojo.isSafari) { // Safari
        // pulled from WebCore/ecma/kjs_window.cpp, line 2536
        selection.collapse(beginning);
    }
}else if(dojo.isIE){ // IE
    var range = dojo.doc.selection.createRange();
    range.collapse(beginning);
    range.select();
}
```

So with Edge it were in the first part. And we had an error...

No we have

```
        if(window.getSelection && !dojo.isIE && !dojo.isEdge){
        var selection = dojo.global.getSelection();
        if(selection.removeAllRanges){ // Mozilla
            if(beginning){
                selection.collapseToStart();
            }else{
                selection.collapseToEnd();
            }
        }else if(dojo.isSafari) { // Safari
            // pulled from WebCore/ecma/kjs_window.cpp, line 2536
            selection.collapse(beginning);
        }
    }else if(dojo.isIE){ // IE
        var range = dojo.doc.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(beginning);
        range.select();
    }else if(dojo.isEdge){ // IE
        var sel = dojo.global.getSelection();
        sel.collapse(beginning);
        sel.select();
    }
```

... sel is good... But, sel.collapse(beginning) is sending an error... "Argument obligatoire" (sorry, It's in French, the translation is... mandatory  arguement ?).... But beginning is defined (and is "true"). I replaced "beginning" by true, btw, same error....

do you have any idea ?

thanks .

Comment: You don't use the right arguments...  
According to MDN, arguments are : `parentNode, offset`.  
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/collapse

Comment: this tricked me. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Damn... ><